# Why python manage.py collectstatic do not copy files to correct location?

Tags: django, docker

The problem I am facing is that my Django project can't find **static files**.

I was struggling with this issue for quite a while hence, 
now **I figured where the problem is** however, I have **no idea how to fix it**.

*Real static files location:*

1. ls /code/jk/static/jk/css/main.css
2. ls /code/jk/static/jk/js/main.js

When running: `RUN (python /code/jk/manage.py collectstatic --noinput)`
**I noticed that this provides me a wrong location:**

```
...
61 static files copied to '/code/jk/jk/static', 2 unmodified.
...
```

There is redundant  `'/code/jk/jk/static'` in the path and I have no idea how to change it.

***settings.py***

```
...
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR]

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
...
```

I am using Django application in docker as following:

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN (pip install -r reqirements.txt)
RUN (python /code/jk/manage.py migrate)
RUN (python /code/jk/manage.py collectstatic --noinput)
RUN (python /code/jk/manage.py migrate)
# clean packages
RUN apt-get clean
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/jk/start_gunicorn.sh"]
```

***start_gunicorn.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /code/jk/
touch ./gunicorn.log
touch ./gunicorn-access.log
tail -n 0 -f ./gunicorn*.log &
#export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectx.settings
exec gunicorn jk.wsgi \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --workers 3 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=./gunicorn.log \
    --access-logfile=./gunicorn-access.log \
"$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

## 1 - The directory collectstatic collects assets in and directories you store your assets sources in aren't the same.

There are two kinds of directory you must know about with django.

- The directories to store your static files sources, from the applications. Usually those are `static` subdirectories in your applications but you can add your own by setting the `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings variable.
- The directory your static files will be collected into for production and serving. This is defined by `STATIC_ROOT` and is **not** the same as the other directories I talked about. In my personnal case, I usually use `/path/to/project/staticfiles` so I can still use `/path/to/project/static` to store sources.

Here you seem to mistake both. If I'm not wrong, your `/code/jk/static` is the directory you expect to get your assets collected into. Yet, you also put some of your sources in it. **You shouldn't add assets by hand in this directory, which is collectstatic's job to retrieve them from your sources locations.**

[EDIT]: You also should not use a directory as both your STATIC_ROOT location and a location to store your assets sources.

## 2 - Collectstatic doesn't move your assets to the wrong location, actually it acts exactly as how you defined it.

Assuming that you expect your assets to be collected into `/code/jk/static`, you should define `STATIC_ROOT` like this :

```
# Note: BASE_DIR value should be `/code/jk`
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And not like this :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

The later defines `PROJECT_ROOT` as "The directory containing the current __file__ which should be `settings.py`". Your `settings.py` should be contained in `/code/jk/jk` which is therefore your `PROJECT_ROOT` value.

So when you define your `STATIC_ROOT` like a `static` subdirectory of your `PROJECT_ROOT` it's perfectly normal to get your assets stored in `/code/jk/jk/static`.

Comment: No, he correctly uses what he calls `STATIC_DIR` as the project-wide static sources. But the webserver doesn't know how to serve `/static`.

Comment: @Melvyn I have no problem with his `STATIC_DIR`. But that's `STATIC_ROOT` that defines where the assets are collected.
To me, serving these files in production seems out of topic in this question.

Comment: hey guys, i have been reading about STATIC_DIR and STATIC_ROOT and I partially agree with both and I also understand that files should be read from STATIC_ROOT. Btw. required files `main.css` and `main.js` are located in both locations. That's why I think that @Melvyn is actaully right. Django doesn;t know how to serve those files. I am gonna try`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` straight away.

Comment: @user2156115 In production, serving those files isn't Django's job anyway. That's why you collect your assets : to make them reachable for your webserver (Apache/nginx/whatever) so it can serve them all after collecting.


In development, you can add some routes to serve them (under certain conditions/restrictions) :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

This is *NOT* suitable for production though.

But this is still out of topic here, since your question was about the location collectstatic put your assets.

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you that should be webserver's role. Later I understood that django is doing what I defined however I still do not understand how to make it work.
`"The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
` I got this message with the improvement you have suggested.

Comment: @user2156115 That's because, as I said in the answer, those are two kinds of location that shouldn't be mixed. You can't use a directory as both a directory to store your source and a directory your collectstatic will populate. Those should be two distinct locations.